# How to limit solution domain in modelica

Tags: openmodelica

I have a very simple model in OpenModelica.

```
model doubleSolution
   Real x ;
equation
   x^2 -4 = 0;
end doubleSolution;
```

There are two mathematical solutions for this problem x={-2,+2}.
The Openmodelica Solver will provide just one result. In this case +2.

What if I'm intested in the other solution?

Using proper start values e.g.  `Real x(Start=-7)` might help as a workaround, but I'm not sure if this is always a robust solution. I'd prefer if I could directly limit the solution range e.g. by `(x < 0)`. Are such bundary conditions possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed using a start value is one option. If that is a robust solution depends on how good the start value is. For this example the Newton-Raphson method is used, which highly depends on a good start value.

You can use `max` and `min` to give a variable a range where it is valid.
Check for example [4.8.1 Real Type of the Modelcia Language Specification](https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.5/class-predefined-types-and-declarations.html#real-type) to see what attributes type `Real` has.

Together with a good start value this should be robust enough and at least give you a warning if the `x` becomes bigger then `0.0`.

```
model doubleSolution
   Real x(max=0, start=-7);
equation
   x^2 -4 = 0;
end doubleSolution;
```

---

Another option would be to add an assert to the equations:

```
assert(value >= min and value <= max , "Variable value out of limit");
```

For the `min` and `max` attribute this assert is added automatically.

Comment: Dear AnHeuermann.  Thanks for your hint. The min/max limits seem to just issue a warning, and not force the solver to limit the solution space.  With start valuse I have the concern, that there might be cases where in the middle of the simulation two solutions might be possible. That's where my concern on stability was coming from. Frankly speaking I didn't experience issues here, up to now. I'm just trying to rule out anything what potentially can go wrong. Maybe this extra care is not required. I'll still use the min/max warning. So if something goes wrong, i can more easily find the cause.